# iOS Passing Interactions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two custom views as subviews on a UIView. I'd like to take every interaction that happens on either of the two subviews and does the same thing to the other subview. This includes all possible interactions like zooming, panning, rotating, etc. What is the easiest/cleanest way to implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only interested in recognizing specific gestures such as zooming, panning, long presses, I would recommend using the `UIGestureRecognizer` subclasses, which allow you to listen for specific types of gestures. Add them all to one view, and whenever one of them is triggered, perform the actions on both of them (such as increasing the scale of your view or moving the content).

Another similar option is to implement the touch handling methods of `UIView` and respond to each tough event directly, mimicking the actions on both views. Those methods are:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //called when a touch or touches begin
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //called when a touch or touches move
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //called when a touch or touches end
}
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //called when a touch or touches are interrupted in some way, such as a phone call
}
```

You can read more about those methods in the `UIResponder` reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

OTOH, if you want to actually synthesize the touch events, you will have to do some hacking. [Here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html) is a tutorial on how to extend the functionality of the UITouch class so that you can simulate a touch programmatically. This is not a solution you should use if you plan to submit this app to the App Store, since it uses private APIs.

Comment: I tried passing on the interactions with the touch handling methods directly with [subview1 touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]. I get an infinite loop with that approach. How would you pass the UIView interaction to the two subviews?

Comment: As you discovered, using that approach will create an infinite loop. Instead, what you want to do is to take the logic that you have inside the `touchesBegan:withEvent` and other methods and apply it to both views at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The two subviews are from third party frameworks for which I do not have access to. I am not seeing a way to do it without simply forwarding the touch events.

Comment: You could use categories - a technique for adding methods to a class you don't have direct access to. Add a method for handling the touch input to the class(es) using a category and have your events call the touch handling methods on both views.